# Paypal payment process in 2 step?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I want to make payment process in 2 step , in first step paypal should collect fund from user account but not transfer to the merchant account .

when i send another request with sucess action at that type paypal should transfer fund to merchant account or if i pass fail action then paypal should refund to user.

is there any way to do this ?

i reefer following URL but cant find solution .

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPECIntegration#id0861K0T0WY4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express Checkout is what you want, but there's [better documentation available](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec).

Basically, what you're after is Authorization and Capture.  When you create your Express Checkout API requests you'll set the PAYMENTACTION to Authorization.  Then, when you're ready to process the payment you call DoCapture and pass in the transaction ID you get back from Express Checkout.

No money is processed until the DoCapture call is processed. If you don't end up needing to process it you can simply do nothing, but that would strand the authorization on the user's account for the default period of time depending on their bank.  Usually 30 days.

It's a better practice to call DoVoid at that point, which would cancel the authorization and release those funds back to the user's account immediately.

If you want to do the same thing with credit cards directly you can use [Payments Pro](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#wpp).  The process is almost identical, except there are actually fewer calls involved.

If you're using PHP I would recommend taking a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It'll make all of this very simple for you, and I can provide 30 min of free training to help you get going if you want, too.